# SAS PROC SQL Error while computing averages

Tags: sql, sas, average, create-table, standard-deviation

I'm trying to compute **annual averages and standard deviations of max and min temperatures,**. My code is as follows:

```
 PROC SQL;
 create table new2 as
  select date,SUM(max_temp) as max_temp,SUM(min_temp) as min_temp,
 SUM(precip) as precip
   from WORK.ROCH_DATA 
    group by date;

 create table average2 as 
  select year(date) as year,(date) as year2,avg(max_temp) as maxavg,
avg(min_temp) as minavg, avg(precip) as avgprecip, std(max_temp) as
stdmaxtemp,
  std(min_temp) as stdmintemp,std(precip) as stdprecip
   from new2
    group by year;
 QUIT;
```

My code ends up spitting something on the likes of this;

[image]

It repeats the year2 and year column (I only want one with the proper year ie 1916.1917) and keeps recalculating a single year. How do i just get it to show me the single calculations of the 50 years in my data? (ie exclude the recalculations)

Comment: The problem is this code:  `year(date) as year,(date) as year`.  It really doesn't make sense to give two columns the same name.

Comment: I've corrected that, but now it presents another problem. Updating question one moment.

Comment: Remove your first proc sql and point the second at your work.ROCH table.

Comment: Also, remove date. It likely has values for every day and SAS will remerge the data together. Other SQL implementations would generate an error. You should be getting a note/warning in your log. Read the log.

Comment: @Reeza is correct. In SQL, all non-aggregated columns must be included in `GROUP BY` clause. This query would fail in practically all RDMS. Why are you aggregated by date and year? Remove the `year2` to return only year aggregates.

Comment: And lastly, what about the proc means answer didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is the 4th time you've asked this same question here's an answer, though I don't see what was wrong with several of the others.
Two ways using proc means. You can use either the output or ODS OUTPUT, I've coded both but it's not required.Your end result is 3 data sets that should have what you want, in different formats likely.

```
proc means data=roch_data noprint stackods;
class date;
format date year4.;
var max_temp min_temp precip;
output out=summary_proc_mean1 mean= std= /autoname;
ods output summary=summary_proc_mean2;
run;
```

Using Proc SQL

```
PROC SQL;
create table average2 as 
  select year(date) as year,
    avg(max_temp) as maxavg,
    avg(min_temp) as minavg, 
    avg(precip) as avgprecip, 
    std(max_temp) as stdmaxtemp,
    std(min_temp) as stdmintemp,
        std(precip) as stdprecip
   from roch_data
    group by year;
 QUIT;
```